# Hide controls not working in flowplayer

Tags: javascript, jquery, video-streaming, flowplayer

Here is my code of flowplayer :-

```
window.onload = function () {

var api = flowplayer();

flowplayer("#hlsjslive", {

plugins: {

controls: {

    all: false,
    play: false

    }
},

splash: true,
embed: false,
ratio: 9/16,

playlist: [
     // a list of type-url mappings in picking order
     [
        { mpegurl: "http://<server-ip>:8081/vod/camera_video.mp4/playlist.m3u8" }
     ],
     [
        { mpegurl: "http://<server-ip>:8081/vod/fast3.mp4/playlist.m3u8" }
     ]

  ]

 })
 }
```

tried everything but i'm unable to hide widget default controls in flowplayer, can anyone have idea about this ?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<style>
    .flowplayer .fp-controls {
        display: none
    }

    .flowplayer .fp-embed,
    .flowplayer .fp-time,
    .flowplayer .fp-duration,
    .flowplayer .fp-remaining,
    .flowplayer .fp-timeline .is-paused,
    .flowplayer .fp-ui {
        background-image: none;
    }

    .flowplayer .fp-help {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

src is [this](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=flowplayer%20%20hide%20controls)